# I just started playing around with scripts. I'm having difficulty clicking on a link

Tags: html, watir

I am having difficulty clicking on a link. I can click the link but nothing happening basically not going to next page.

Steps I am following:

1. log in to www.jetstar.com.au
2. click on Travel agents link (I need to click on this link)

Please find web elements from the site

```
<span class="text">
    <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 34px; height: 12px;" alt="Travel">
        <canvas width="42" height="13" style="left: 0px; top: -1px; width: 42px; height: 13px;">
         </canvas>
   <cufontext>Travel</cufontext>.  
   <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" style="width: 44px; height: 12px;" alt=" agents"> 
        <canvas width="50" height="13" style="left: 0px; top: -1px; width: 50px; height: 13px;">
        </canvas>
       <cufontext> 
        agents
        </cufontext>
  </cufon>
</span>
```

and my code is to generate the link

```
@ie.link(:id, "ctl04_ctl07_rptGlobalNavigation_hypGlobalNav_0").span(:alt, "Travel").click
```

and also i tried fire_event didn't worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Michael i am using 'Watir' to make it simple I'm using plain code now. Please find below code: require 'watir'
browser = Watir::IE.new
browser.goto 'www.jetstar.com.au'
browser.link(:href, "https://agenthub.jetstar.com/newtradeloginagent.aspx?culture=en-AU").fire_event("onClick")        basically its clicks the link but not going to next page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the Travel Agents link on the home page when not signed in is the same as after signing in, the line:

```
@ie.link(:id, "ctl04_ctl07_rptGlobalNavigation_hypGlobalNav_0").span(:alt, "Travel").click
```

Will not work because:

- There is no span with alt attribute of "Travel". It is a cufon element instead.
- The Travel Agents link ID seems dynamic and so might change. For example, when not signed in the id is showing as "ctl02_ctl07_rptGlobalNavigation_hypGlobalNav_0".

I would try locating the link with something that is less likely to change - eg the href attribute. Try:

```
@ie.link(:href => /agenthub\.jetstar\.com/).click
```

Comment: Hi tried with the above code: @ie.link(:href => /agenthub\.jetstar\.com/).click   still no luck seems code is ok its clicks as i said in my previous comments it clicks the link but not going to next page. tried regular expressions still no luck.

Comment: Do you get the same problem when trying to click the Travel agents link on the home page without logging in?

Comment: Hi Justin, tried without Login and after login same issue.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? As well, what version of Watir (Watir, Watir-Classic and Watir-Webdriver)?

Comment: IE V.11 and watir-1.5.1.1192. Just 'watir'. I am not using watir classic or Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: Watir 1.5.1 would be somewhere back in 2007. In comparison IE11 was released in 2013. I would not be surprised if that version of Watir had issues with IE11. Is there a reason you are trying to learn such an old version? Why not upgrade to the latest version, which because Watir-Classic after Watir 4.0. Or switch to Watir-Webdriver, which has the same API but a larger user base?

Comment: Hi Justin, sorry for the late reply . I installed latest version rubyinstaller-2.2.1-x64. however i am getting errors. everything installed successfully.

Comment: below are the errors :1) If i use require 'watir-classic' or 'watir -webdriver'. I am getting below errors :C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)  or if i use 2) require 'watir' then i am getting flight1.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Watir::IE (NameError). below is my code:require 'Watir'
#require 'watir-webdriver'
#require 'watir-classic'
browser = Watir::IE.new
browser = Watir::Browser.start "www.sample.com.au".

Comment: For the "uninitialized constant Watir::IE (NameError)", you need to be using `Watir::Browser` instead of `Watir::IE`. For the "ffi_c (LoadError)", you should be able to find an answer online. I am pretty sure there have been other Watir questions related to that.

Comment: Hi Justin not sure still couldn't detect why i am unable to open IE .tried downloading dev kit and followed instruction as mentioned by fellow users. however good thing is using web -driver i can able to open firefox. so i don't want to investigate now on IE. if i found solution i will post my comments. Thanks and closing this issue.